# using Oauth 2 to acces Gmail API in web application not installed on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail

I want to access gmail api in a web application which is not installed on Google App Engine
using oauth 2.0.

I looked into oauth and it seems that we need client_id and client secret to get access token.

Client_id and Client secret is given once we create project on google app engine

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Link to the developer's console which will let you create a new project:
https://console.developers.google.com

More details on the webserver oauth flow:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: But I dont want to create app on GAE

Comment: The project and appengine app are two distinct things.  The project is a way to encapsulate a group of resources.  It may include an optional appengine app, but you do not need to use it.